# How can a watchdog timer be cleared in Mplab Harmony?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplabx, mplab-harmony

Using Mplab Code Configurator (MCC) it's easy to clear watchdog timer, for example i created a project for a `PIC 16F15324T` and in my code i only have to call the function this way: `CLRWDT();`

In Mplab Harmony how can we do the same?
I created a project for a `PIC32MX470F512L` and i'm not finding how to clear the watchdog timer.

Answer (score 1):

In the harmony_help_volume_V_partii.pdf you will find:

```
PLIB_WDT_TIMERClear(WDT_ID_0);      //resets WDT Timer
```

Comment: havent found this on harmonyv2 for the PIC32MX470F512L :(